# How to extract URLs from cell values without timing out?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a long spreadsheet with over 100k rows, where a particular column has values with mostly values including links. The values hold links without using any function (like hyperlink), and I'm trying to find the most efficient way to extract them in a different column.

I created a spreadsheet where I'm using the bellow script to extract the urls (column I) from the values in column H):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_y0PD3n35AKNEAcvCLKBGEmTpThjD3LQTScndaytpWA/edit#gid=0

The problem I'm facing is that most of the time, I get processing errors, where the function timed out. What's the best way to extract URLs then?

```
function RichTextLinks(rangeA1, dynamic_reference) {
if (typeof rangeA1 !== 'string') {
throw new Error('RichTextLinks expected rangeA1 to be a text string like "A2:A42" but got ' + Object.prototype.toString.call(rangeA1) + ' instead.');
}
const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeA1);
const richText = range.getRichTextValues();
return richText.map(row => row.map(value => value.getLinkUrl()));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's only timing out with that? I just made a test with 100,000 rich text links and it took less than a minute to complete. Can you give more context about what you are doing because maybe its another part of the script that is timing out? Also can you clarify why you are trying to do it with a custom function and not just run a script from the editor?

Comment: @iansedano thanks for reviewing! Just heads up that I'm new with Scripts. My spreadsheet does have many more formulas and calculations and I'm thinking that maybe it takes too long to process everything. So the RichTextLinks function either stays "Loading" or gives an #ERROR. I'm using a function because the data is dynamic and keeps changing, but also I don't know how I could run everything from the editor automating it daily. Any example would be great if you think that would be better? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Custom functions have a 30 second timeout, execute the script from the Editor

From the [guide on custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> A custom function call must return within 30 seconds.

I suspect 100k rows is just above that limit!

#### Use triggers

You can for instance use [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to update values. For instance, a time-driven trigger [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder). You could make it run every 15 minutes, for example. It depends on what you need it for, just watch you don't run over the [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).

```js
function RichTextLinks() {
    const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("H3:H");
    const richText = range.getRichTextValues();
    const hyperlinks = richText.map(row => row.map(value => value.getLinkUrl()));

    const outputRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("I3:I");
    outputRange.setValues(hyperlinks)
}
```

You can manually set a trigger following instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). Or run this function **once**.

```js
function createTimeDrivenTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('RichTextLinks')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(15)
      .create();
```

You may be tempted by the `onEdit` trigger, which will run every time you make an edit to the spreadsheet. But watch out, because since the function takes so long to run, it won't work very well.

Just in case, to run a script manually from the script editor, you just need to select the function you want to run here:

[image]

and then press "Run"!

#### References

- [guide on custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [clock trigger builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)
- [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).
- [managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Comment: This works wonderfully well with a time trigger! thanks so much @iansenado you are a leyend!

Answer (score 0):

Use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to do batch request on the whole column.

It should solve timeout problem.